# Any standard way to define what methods an object require to work with a library ? (much like an interface)

Tags: ruby

Consider that I work full time with Ruby (and eventually Rails) so I definitely know the language

Recently I was developing a gem which needed to interact with some objects sent by the programmer and those object needed to behave in some ways.

Considering the **duck-typing** code-style which I love, I must admit that in this case interfaces (like Java/C# and such) were useful, not for anything about implementation but for documenting purposes.

I usually write a readme file, then I put there: *The method accepts an object that should respond to this and that and blah blah blah*.
The main issue with this approach is that I forget to update the readme when something changes and I didn't find a solution to this.

Are there any library or something similar that can help me generating such readme by watching at code or code documentation? Typing as documentation on top of class something like (please notice that this is a syntax invented on the fly, with some YAML in it):

```
# @Interface
# method_name:
#   param1_name:
#     type: String
#   param2_name:
#     type: Object
#     respond_to:
#       - method_1:
#         param1_name:
#           type: String
#     returns:
#       type: Object
#       respond_to:
```

...Something like this (this was just an idea). If there is something that parses code in some way it's even better but I know Ruby is more or less impossible to parse due to it's *dynamicness*

Any suggestion, **best-practises** or a standard way on how to do this? I want programmers to feel comfortable when they write code that have to interact with a gem written by me.

Comment: I expect a comment about the -1 and the closing vote, I'm asking for something important about a programming language: how to allow other programmers to interact (correctly) with my library

Comment: I don't know about the -1, but three of the four close votes so far are "primarily opinion-based". I'm not voting on this one, but that's hard to argue with. If you can make a case that this is a question that can have a definite answer rather than an call for an open-ended discussion of opinions, you might want to edit your question or add a comment to make that case, because it's one vote away from being closed.

Comment: What about making a statistic over the most used gem in github? I think that can be considered the "standard way" because we don't have a centralized place to define standards for such things. Much like it's standard to use methods with question mark at the end instead of is_something? I can check it, I think what Jakub suggests seems the more logical (I didn't check, the answer may also be **there is no standard way right now, we can suggest the followings: blah1, blah2, blah3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An unit (integration) test/spec is the best documentation of a class (library). Test is actually way more expressive then a Java interface which basically ensures just a method contract (name, arguments and its types, return type), but not the method behavior and additional conditions.

Write focused integration tests for methods contract and reference them from README. Something like: “this method can be used to bla bla bla and it expects bla bla, see THIS spec for a detailed specification what the method expects”. RSpec is very well readable and expressive so it can be used as a contract documentation.

Comment: I can't expect people starting using my gem by reading tests. Tests are helpful when you are searching for a specific behavior of the gem. Imagine my test suite is 3000+ tests (for example, webmock gem), I can't expect people understand how to use it by reading tests, it's insane. I will expect them to provide me a good README with infos on how to use it. Same here, tests are good to ensure everything is implemented as it should, but if I expect a rather complex object, I want it to be documented

Comment: Well, then write focused integration tests for contract and reference them from README. Something like: “this method can be used to bla bla bla and it expects bla bla, see THIS spec for a detailed specification what the method expects”. Rspec is very well readable and expressive so it can be used as a contract documentation.

Comment: **This** sounds like a good idea (more clever, you should update your answer).

Comment: I'll wait a bit to mark it as an answer because maybe there are other ways to make such a thing but this seems really like the right one. It would be lovely if there is a way for rspec to run something like a single test over a file without having to "setup rspec environment" (rspec dir, spec helper, just execute the code and see if the test passes)

Comment: Ok running around repositories, looks like this is the most used way to do it right now. So I'm accepting this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Rspec documentation on describing a shared groups of contract like tests(sort of like an interface) that you can use with whatever types should implement the interface:

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-8/docs/example-groups/shared-examples#shared-examples-group-included-in-two-groups-in-one-file

Possibly you could also have an abstract base class(just raise NotImplementedError with an explanation) which you can derive from.
The main benefit is that you can use Rdoc to document the interface on the abstract class as opposed to the tests which may feel a bit weird. The side benefit is if someone forgets to implement a method you get a slightly more useful error.

Edit:
There is also an interface gem but it hasn't been touched in over 3 years.

http://rubygems.org/gems/interface

Comment: Sounds very useful, expecially considering that after you have implemented all the methods, you can stop inheriting avoiding overhead. Probably is even better if you do it through a module so you have inheritance "free"